# Serialize instance of object via memory dump

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, memoization

Is it possible to dump an in-memory object and then close the node process then load it back in? I am thinking about a memoization function that is cached between processes.

I would love to be able to `memoize` a cache between processes.

The issue is that no memoization library serializes instances of objects.

I was playing around with this library [memoize-fs](https://github.com/borisdiakur/memoize-fs)

```
async function fun(a) {
  return new Hello(a);
}

async function fun_(a) {
  return memoize.fn(fun, {}).then((memFn) => {
    return memFn(a);
  });
}

fun('meow').then(console.log);
fun_('meow').then(console.log);
```

First time this runs:

```
Hello { sound: 'meow' }
Hello { sound: 'meow' }
```

Second time this runs:

```
Hello { sound: 'meow' }
{ sound: 'meow' }
```

Comment: Serializing is a pain in js for sure, closures and such make it fairly non trivial. Is it possible for you write your own serailizing stuff for what you're interested in?